# I want to compute the fewest turns and fewest accumulative angle change from a single origin to a set of destinations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, sdna

I want to compute the fewest turns and fewest accumulative angle change from a single origin to a set of destinations.

The origin and destinations are shown on this map. The flag is the origin, all the other points labelled with a number are the destinations. [image]

As the origin and destinations are not located on the link, firstly, I find the nearest link ID of each origin and destinations. Secondly, I want to use **Integral Analysis** to compute the fewest turns(and fewest accumulative angle change respectively) from the origin to each destination and get a new field in the shapefile recording the number of turns from the origin to each destination.

Or record the fewest accumulative angle change from the origin to each destination.

The roads are two ways.

In routing and analysis metric, I choose ANGULAR.

Radii: n

Radial metric:ANGULAR

Weighting: Link

Is my selection right?

I am confused between Routing and analysis metric and Radial metric, and weighting, Origin weight, Destination weight, Custom metric field, Intermediate link filter, Advanced config

How to fill in the other sections:

[image]

---

Using @Sideshow Bob 's answer, I tried the accumulative angle change using *Specific Origin Accessibility Maps*.The setting is as follows:[image]

And the output shapefile's attribute table is as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it is *possible* to do this by passing some advanced config options to Integral Analysis, this is what the `Specific Origin Accessibility Map` tool is for. (Whichever way you do it an sDNA+ license is needed). It has far fewer options to set and they should be self explanatory for this task.

Angular metric is correct to record cumulative angular change. There isn't a setting to directly record total number of turns, but there are two workarounds:

1. in sDNA - fix split links using *Prepare Network*. Then in `specific origin accessibility map` choose custom metric but don't supply any custom metric field. This will assume the custom data for each link always equals 1, so you will be measuring the number of turns plus one from which it is easy to get number of turns.
2. in sDNA+ you can do it by setting routing and analysis metric to `hybrid`;  in advanced config put `lineformula=0;juncformula=1` to count all links as 0 and all junctions (turns) as 1.

The other settings you asked about aren't needed for the task at hand. All the info you ask for should be spread over [this doc page](http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v3_4_5/guide_to_individual_tools.html) (not all in one place as many of these options are common to several tools). In brief:

> I am confused between Routing and analysis metric and Radial metric

- Routing and Analysis Metric - determines how agents choose the shortest path through the network (routing) and how accessibility is reported (mean distance, NQPD, etc).
- Radial metric - determines how radius is measured if you are doing local analysis rather than radius *n*. The default is Euclidean and measured in the spatial units of your data so if your network is projected onto a grid measured in metres then the radius is in metres. But setting other values would allow you determine local radius in other ways, e.g. angular, custom, hybrid or even presets such as pedestrian and cyclist.

Radius affects everything, so for example routes longer than the radius are discarded in computing betweenness; *Links, Length, Mean Distance* etc all measure only links within the radius from each origin.

> and weighting, Origin weight, Destination weight
>   Custom metric field,
>   Intermediate link filter, Advanced config

Weighting (in general) allows you to specify that some links are more important than others, e.g. if you think they will generate more traffic you could weight them higher, or weight a pedestrian analysis by retail floor area, etc. Links that cannot be origins or destinations at all (e.g. motorways) can be given a weight of 0 if desired. Alternatively you may decide to analyse accessibility or flows only to a specific set of destinations such as metro stations. Setting origin or destination weights appropriately allows for any of these scenarios.

The *Weighting* option itself specifies whether the weights you supply apply to complete network links (which may be built of multiple polylines), or to the polylines in the network, or alternatively are to be interpreted as weights per unit length.

http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v3_4_5/analysis-spec.html#weighting-type

> Custom metric field,

Custom metric field is where the data for a custom metric comes from. So if you had travel time data per link for example you could choose custom metric and set the data field here. This is a legacy (sDNA) option which has been superseded by the more flexible hybrid metrics in sDNA+.

> Intermediate link filter

Restricts analysis only to routes which pass through the specified links, so you can make maps like this:

[image: Example of Intermediate Link Filter]

> Advanced config

Where the rabbit hole gets deeper:

http://www.cardiff.ac.uk/sdna/wp-content/downloads/documentation/manual/sDNA_manual_v3_4_5/guide_to_individual_tools.html#advanced-configuration-and-command-line-options

Comment: Thank you. I tried to compute the cumulative angular change of each link using Specific Origin Accessibility Maps. There are two fields in the resulting shapefile's attribute table that I don't understand. "AnalMet" and "Length", what do they stand for? Which one of them is the cumulative angular change from the origin to the destination link?@Sideshow Bob

Comment: I added two pictures in the questions of the process and result of the cumulative angular change. Thank you.

Comment: AnalMet = Analytic Metric, which in this case you set to Angular, so this is the output you are looking for. Length is the length of the route in the units of your spatial data (presumably metres).